# Self signed certificate export from development to production

Tags: wcf

If x.509 certificate(self signed) created in development server is imported to production, does the client need to update the reference again. The certificate is used in wcf. The endpoints are dynamic i.e swichting of url from development to production is done in database .

Answer (score 0):

No, the cert is the cert, as long as the client and the server are aligned you should be good